# Does the HTML DOMs have any effect on one another when run simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to know if the DOM elements have any effect on one another if one doesn't stop loading before another command is executed. For example; an `onload` event is still loading but the user happened to scroll before it stops, triggering an `onscroll` event.
Is this possible; if yes then how to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from things like Web Workers, generally JavaScript in the browser is single-threaded.  Only one event handler will run at a time.